# Unresolved compilation problem while executing Java in VS Code

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

I have been trying to execute this code in VS Code

```java
    class test1 extends Thread
    {
       public void run()
       {
           for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
           System.out.println("Task 1");
       }


    }
    class task2 extends Thread
    {
      public void run()
      {
          for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
          System.out.println("Task 2");
      }
    }
    public class app
    {
         public static void main(final String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
             final test1 t1 = new test1();
             final task2 t2 = new task2();
            t1.start();
            t2.start();
        }
    }
```

but it shows an exception in main thread:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 

        at app.main(test1.java:21)
```

(see [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/95TfD.png))

I tried different IDEs(like BlueJ) and this code is working fine with them. So what exactly is the problem I am facing while executing it in VS Code?

Comment: You will need to tell us what the error is.  Show us the exception message and the stacktrace.

Comment: I have added a screenshot of that error message. Please, have a look at it.

Comment: OK.  So it says there is a compilation error.  What is the compilation error message?

Comment: Please post text, not links to images of text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you’re having a file with a name `test1.java`, but the java compiler requires that the file name matches the name of the `public` class inside.

Try either

- renaming the file to `app.java`
- renaming the class `app` → `test1`, but then you’ll have to rename existing `test1` to something else
- make the `app` not `public` (and you will still be able to run it)

(I’m not sure why VS Code doesn’t report this problem properly.)

Comment: Thanks a lot, man! It is indeed true that the compiler requires file name to be matched with the name of public class inside, so just removing the public keyword makes my program to run without any error.